# How may I test whether a document is being compiled by tex4ht?

Tags: tex4ht

Is there a way to programatically test whether the current document is being compiled by `tex4ht`?

What I am looking for is something like `\iftexfourht`, or perhaps some `\@ifundefined{...}`, in order to make `\variable` expand either to `$#1$` or to `\textit{#1}` conditionally upon whether or not `tex4ht` is in charge.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand \variable [1]
{%
 \iftexfourht
  \textit{#1}%
 \else
  $#1$%
 \fi
}

\begin{document}
Let's talk about \variable{x}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\@ifundefined{HCode}{NO HT}{YES HT}`, but I wouldn't rely on it; anybody can define anything, so someone can define `\HCode` even `tex4ht` is not active.